# Selenium webdriver: Unable to send keys In a new popup window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using selenium web-driver I am trying to put region name In the text box In  new popup screen and click on save button. I using the below script for that

```java
String mainWindowHandle1=driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle1 );

driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_imgAddRegion")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

java.util.Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();

Iterator<String> ite1 = s1.iterator();
while(ite1.hasNext())
{
    String popupHandle=ite1.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle1))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle).findElement(By.id("txtRegionName")).sendKeys("South Region");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtRegionName")).sendKeys("South Region");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click();
```

By doing this I am able to open the new popup screen to enter the region but, I am unable to send keys [region name] and save the text.Even I am not getting any failed report when I run the test.

Comment: After switching to the popup window, can you interact with any of its elements? Or is it a problem specifically with the txtRegionName element?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to iFrames presence. 
Look in the HTML code and check if the text field that you are trying to send keys to and the save button are included in some sort of iFrame.
If so, you will need to do something like:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("framename");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtRegionName")).sendKeys("South Region");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave")).click();
```

Hope it helps!